# Why is `std::optional<T>::operator=` deleted when T contains a `const` data member?

Tags: c++, c++17, assignment-operator, stdoptional

The following code would lead to compiler errors:

```
#include <optional>

class A {
};
class B {
private:
    const A a;
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    std::optional<B> bo1;
    bo1 = b;
}
```

On gcc, for example, the error reads:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:12:7: error: uninitialized const member in 'class B'
12 |     B b;
   |       ^
main.cpp:7:13: note: 'const A B::a' should be initialized
7 |     const A a;
  |             ^
main.cpp:14:11: error: use of deleted function 'std::optional<B>& std::optional<B>::operator=(std::optional<B>&&)'
14 |     bo1 = b;
   |           ^
In file included from main.cpp:1:
/lib/gcc-head/include/c++/12.0.0/optional:663:11: note: 'std::optional<B>& std::optional<B>::operator=(std::optional<B>&&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
663 |     class optional
    |           ^~~~~~~~
/lib/gcc-head/include/c++/12.0.0/optional:663:11: error: use of deleted function 'std::_Enable_copy_move<true, false, true, false, _Tag>& std::_Enable_copy_move<true, false, true, false, _Tag>::operator=(std::_Enable_copy_move<true, false, true, false, _Tag>&&) [with _Tag = std::optional<B>]'
In file included from /lib/gcc-head/include/c++/12.0.0/optional:43,
             from main.cpp:1:
/lib/gcc-head/include/c++/12.0.0/bits/enable_special_members.h:248:5: note: declared here
248 |     operator=(_Enable_copy_move&&) noexcept                         = delete;
    |     ^~~~~~~~
```

On MSVC, as another example, the error reads:

```
main.cpp
<source>(14): error C2280: 'std::optional<B> &std::optional<B>::operator =(const std::optional<B> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
C:/data/msvc/14.29.29917-Pre/include\optional(445): note: compiler has generated 'std::optional<B>::operator =' here
C:/data/msvc/14.29.29917-Pre/include\optional(445): note: 'std::optional<B> &std::optional<B>::operator =(const std::optional<B> &)': function was implicitly deleted because a base class invokes a deleted or inaccessible function 'std::_Deleted_move_assign<std::_Optional_construct_base<_Ty>,_Ty> &std::_Deleted_move_assign<std::_Optional_construct_base<_Ty>,_Ty>::operator =(const std::_Deleted_move_assign<std::_Optional_construct_base<_Ty>,_Ty> &)'
        with
        [
            _Ty=B
        ]
C:/data/msvc/14.29.29917-Pre/include\xsmf_control.h(131): note: 'std::_Deleted_move_assign<std::_Optional_construct_base<_Ty>,_Ty> &std::_Deleted_move_assign<std::_Optional_construct_base<_Ty>,_Ty>::operator =(const std::_Deleted_move_assign<std::_Optional_construct_base<_Ty>,_Ty> &)': function was implicitly deleted because a base class invokes a deleted or inaccessible function 'std::_Deleted_copy_assign<std::_Optional_construct_base<_Ty>,_Ty> &std::_Deleted_copy_assign<std::_Optional_construct_base<_Ty>,_Ty>::operator =(const std::_Deleted_copy_assign<std::_Optional_construct_base<_Ty>,_Ty> &)'
        with
        [
            _Ty=B
        ]
C:/data/msvc/14.29.29917-Pre/include\xsmf_control.h(92): note: 'std::_Deleted_copy_assign<std::_Optional_construct_base<_Ty>,_Ty> &std::_Deleted_copy_assign<std::_Optional_construct_base<_Ty>,_Ty>::operator =(const std::_Deleted_copy_assign<std::_Optional_construct_base<_Ty>,_Ty> &)': function was explicitly deleted
        with
        [
            _Ty=B
        ]
Compiler returned: 2
```

As long as we remove the `const` keyword in `const A a;`, the errors disappear.
According to the [referenced standard on std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator%3D), there are cases when certain overloads of the =operator would be removed, depending on the std::is_...able_v tests. In this case, why would the `const` keyword affect some of these tests?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`optional` uses the object's `=`.

A class with a `const` data member cannot be assigned to.  It can only be constructed.

Try this:

```
B b0;    
B b1;
b0=b1;
```

`optional` doesn't work because `B` doesn't.

Also, try `static_assert(!std::is_copy_assignable_v<B>);`, which passes.

now, `std::optional` has a "back door" here.

```
B b;
std::optional<B> bo1;
bo1.emplace(b);
```

which constructs instead of assigns.

Optional could, in theory, fall back on this; but if the contents exist, it would need to destroy it then emplace a new object.  That is risky, messes up semantics, and a bad plan to do silently.

Comment: Rule of thumb, never use `optional`'s `operator=` with `T` on the right hand side. It's semantics is broken in my opinion because it mixes levels of abstraction. Without it, there is no doubt how many things should behave (like `T const` or `T&`).

Answer (score 2):

A const data member can't be modified after the object is constructed.  Thus a properly working `operator=` is impossible.